# Wordpress themes not generating a proper homepage on a server folder

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I am using a wordpress theme which I have modified a bit, based on the "Revera" Wordpress theme.

I have used it on other sites and it has worded fine. However, I have always installed it in the root of the domain. This time I have installed it on http://www.gas-sense.co.uk/blog
It isn't generating the usual homepage layout ( see http://www.georgeedwards.co )

Just wondering if the themes are typically setup to trigger the homepage layout? and if that is defined in a particular section of the php ?

Comment: i don't get your question clearly as i know that you can install wordpress theme on root of your domain. themes are meant to be installed in wp-conetnt/themes folder. kindly elaborate your question a bit more may be u have installed wordpress in /blog. ??

Comment: Yes, wordpress core files are kept in the /blog folder. the theme has then been installed through the wp-admin terminal.

Comment: goto wp-admin dashboard than check in Settings > Reading that you have selected a static page for home page or may be in your theme there is a home page settings you need to change it to another static page and set blog page to another page other than blog

Answer (score 0):

The root folder is not a problem, you probably didn't set up the site url correctly, read the docs bellow

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Neither of the links under settings > general show the root, they are both pointing to the domain.co.uk/blog folder. So I assume they are correct unless I have misunderstood the guidance?

Comment: And which page do you have set up for homepage? Is it possible that your homepage is your latest blogposts?